# Are there other books about the history of Middle-Earth?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I've read these books about the history of Middle-Earth.

- The Shaping of Middle-earth
- The Return of the Shadow
- The Treason of Isengard
- The War of the Ring
- Sauron Defeated

and really liked them.

What other books by Tolkien (father or son) detail the history of Middle-Earth?

Comment: The books you have read are part of the 12-volume series called literally the "History of Middle Earth". You can find more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_Middle-earth. The wiki article of Tolkien's Legendarium might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have learnt a lot from [The Letters of J.R.R. Tokien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Letters_of_J._R._R._Tolkien). You have to do some fishing around, but there are gems hidden in it.

As a Tengwar exercise, [The Road Goes Ever On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Goes_Ever_On) (a song book with Donald Swan) can be fun, also these are "canonical", "Tolkien-approved" songs. He even made the melody of *Ai! Laurie Lantar Lasse Surinen!* himself, as a sort of Gregorian tune.

Of course, the [Silmarillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion) and [Unfinished Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfinished_Tales) are both important works, both containing stories from the First to the Third Age.

If you want all the tragedy of Turin's story, read [The Children of Hurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_H%C3%BArin) for all the wonderful details.

If, like me, you like Pauline Baynes' illustrations (which are also "Tolkien-approved"), I urge you to have a look at [Bilbo's Last Song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbo%27s_Last_Song) and [The Adventures of Tom Bombadil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tom_Bombadil) (The latter also contains more written information).

I *think* that's mostly it.